# Not all tests are run in parameterised NUnit TestFixture containing arrays

Tags: c#, testing, nunit, resharper, parameterized

I have a test class as follows:

```
[TestFixture("someurl1", new[] { "param1", "param2" }, 15)]
[TestFixture("someurl2", new[] { "param3" }, 15)]
public class my_test
{
    public my_test(string url, string[] fields, int someVal)
    {
        // test setup
    }
}
```

When running this test in ReSharper 6.1 and NUnit 2.5.10, the test is not run twice, as expected, it only runs once. In the test results I see listed

```
my_test("someurl1", System.String[], 15)
```

This makes me think that the two fixtures are being treated as the same, and that NUnit isn't differentiating between the string arrays in the two tests.

As a workaround I have added a dummy parameter in the constructor. If I set this to a different value for each fixture, then all the tests run.

Is it not possible to have TestFixtures with arrays containing different values? I've just upgraded from ReSharper 5 so I'm wondering if that is related. I have read about some issues with parameterised tests in 6.x.

Comment: Does it work in the NUnit runner?

Comment: Also, thanks for pointing out that you can have parameterised test fixtures, as I didn't know this was possible.

Comment: Just tried in the NUnit runner and that runs all the tests successfully. I think it could be related to the ReSharper upgrade.

Comment: I've had problems before with resharper's runner.  I just stick to the NUnit one now.

Answer (score 4):

```
[TestFixture("someurl1", "param1|param2", 15)]
[TestFixture("someurl2", "param3", 15)]
public class my_test
{
    private string[] _fields;

    public my_test(string url, string fieldList, int someVal)
    {
        _fields = fieldList.Split('|');
        // test setup
    }

    [Test]
    public void listFields()
    {
        foreach (var field in _fields)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(field);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is related to newing-up an array in the TestFixture constructor, I read somewhere  that you can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating individual tests under it as a generic TestFixture??? Something like

```
[TestFixture]
public class my_test
{
    private bool my_test(string url, string[] fields, int someVal)
    {
        // test setup
        return DidTestCompleteOk;
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestURL1()
    {
        Assert.IsTrue( my_test("someurl1", new[] { "param1", "param2" }, 15));
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestURL2()
    {
        Assert.IsTrue( my_test("someurl2", new[] { "param3" }, 15) );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this is the absolute error message if ANYTHING goes wrong in a parameterized test fixture's constructor.  You don't get the actual exception information returned like when stuff fails in other code.

So you probably should move your setup code to a `[SetUp]` or `[TestFixtureSetUp]` or reallly be sure your constructor is executing without error. But really you should be doing the first suggestion, and only save the test fixture parameters in the constructor and do something with them in another method.